# Is editing anything in /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks acceptable?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/multi_robot_collision_avoidance)(The tutorial mentions that it's currently failure, but my question seems irrelevant to the failure), I downloaded the package to my own ros directory.

```
hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/collvoid/collvoid
```

However, in the tutorial it mentions patching amcl by

```
roscd collvoid
mv amcl.patch ../navigation
roscd navigation
patch -p1 < amcl.patch
```

It moves amcl.patch to navigation package like they are in same directory, for which is in /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks. In my understanding, I should not change anything in /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks, so move amcl.patch to navigation and patch it seems weird to me.

Is there anything wrong with my understanding?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47354/is-editing-anything-in-/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks-acceptable?/) by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1371 on 2012-11-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-11-02**:
They may be assuming that you have your local copy of the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(The official answer is) no.

Use [Overlays](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays).
The premise is that you get the source, and modify that in a controlled manner.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-11-02**:
Not only the "official answer", but also the correct answer. Don't do it. Use overlays.

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-11-02**:
Got it! Thanks~